# Applying RequireJS to a modular one page application

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I actually have two questions concerning requirejs and singleton objects. I want to form a singleton object playing the role of my application core and pass it to modules as a parameter. How should this be done?

The other issue I have is related to a private object inside the application core. It's suppose to act as a container for modules but for some reason when I try to start the application, this container seems to have those modules but it can't be looped through. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's an example code of the situation:

```
// applicationConfig.js
require.config({
   baseUrl: 'js',
   paths: {
      jquery: 'jquery-3.1.1.min',
      core: 'utils/applicationCore',
      domReady: '../lib/domReady'
   }
});
require(['modules']);

// modules.js
define(['core', 'domReady'], function(Core, domReady) {
   require([
      'modules/module1'
   ]);

   domReady(function() {
      var modules = Core.getModules();
      var name = '';
      for (name in modules) {
         modules[name].creator(); // Start a module...
      }
   });
});

// applicationCore.js
define(function() {
   return (function() {
     var _modules = {};

     return {
        add: function(name, creator) {
           _modules[name] = {
              creator: creator
           };
        },
        getModules: function() {
           return _modules;
        }
     }
  }());
});

// module1.js
define(['core', 'jquery'], function(Core, $) {
   Core.add('module1', function() {
      // Module constructor function.
   });
});
```

Comment: RE question 2: why would you want to replicate functional already provided by RequireJS? You would need to have a really really specific case and even then you're introducing a race condition that RequireJS prevents.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! First of all, my case is pretty specific and the main reason I started looking into requirejs was to be able to manage loading the required javascript files (aka modules in my case) and hence making the application maintainable and efficient. What do you mean by a race condition?

Comment: I am definitely not saying don't use RequireJS. You want a loader for sure and require JS is an excellent one. What I mean is that it asynchronously loads, caches, and instantiates modules for you. This handles a lot of concurrency issues out of the box including providing safe Singletons. In fact, every module is a Singleton

Comment: Basically, don't build your own module cache, RequireJS already provides that - it is by definition of how works.

Comment: I'm basically adding requirejs to an existing application to help manage module loading. For this reason it's not reasonable for me to start modifying the basic structure too much. The application that I'm working on is a framework-free implementation and I would like find a way to make future work a bit easier.